# Magento 2 - Get page cache by tag name in cache warmer

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache, cache-warmer

I am creating a **cache warmer**, before crawling page to **re-generate cache**, I want to check **if page cache is created**.

Let's say, I have a product with the `ID 156` now cache tag would be `catalog_product_156`, now what would be the criteria to get cache by tag name?